# Proper way to SQL select and update

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm using github.com/bmizerany/pq against a Postgres database. I need to select all the rows in the "todos" table, and for each row check for condition and update the row accordingly. Pseudo codes:

```
rows, _ := dbConn.Query("SELECT id, condition, task FROM todos")

for rows.Next() {
    var Id int
    var Condition int
    var Task string
    rows.Scan(&Id, &Condition, &Task)
    if Condition == 0 {
           UpdateTask(Id, Task)
    }
}
```

The UpdateTask() function will issue a SQL update statement to update the row.

Will issuing SQL update within a SELECT query lock the database? Is this the proper way of doing such update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, at *minimum* you should be doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` so you lock the rows against other `SELECT ... FOR [SHARE|UPDATE]` access. You must do this inside a transaction and hold that transaction until you update the last row and `commit`.

The rows you `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` *not* locked against normal `SELECT`; they're still readable to other transactions that aren't using `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE`.

Better still, try to rephrase the whole thing as an `UPDATE ... FROM` or other set-based operation where you do all the work in a single query. It'll generally perform massively better than a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` followed by a stream of `UPDATE`s.